# how to get multiple data when update data with django?

Tags: python, django

I want to update data using multiple checkbox
this is my view.py

```
def update_kel_stat(request, id):
if request.method == "POST":
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql = "UPDATE keluargapeg_dipkeluargapeg SET KelStatApprov='3' WHERE (PegUser = %s )" % id 
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

and this is my template.html

```
<form method="post" action="" name="kel" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% for keluarga in kels %}
    <tr id="{{ keluarga.KelID }}">
        <td>
            <a href="#">{{ keluarga.KelNamaLengkap }}</a>
        </td>
        <td>{{ keluarga.KelStatApprov }}</td>
        <td>{{ keluarga.KelKetRevisi }}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="kel[]"
                   value="{{ keluarga.KelID }}"></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
<tr>
    <td>
        <button type="button" name="btn_delete" id="btn_delete"
                class="btn btn-success"
                onClick="setDeleteAction();">Approve
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
</form>
```

how to get multiple value from checkbox in template.html to django view.py?

Comment: Why are you using raw SQL? Especially why are you using string substitution with raw SQL, which is an obvious vector for SQL injection attacks?

Comment: i just want simple way

Comment: Then use the functionality Django gives you: models and forms.

Comment: actually i have models and from, but i just want to make simple function to update one field by clicking button.

Comment: yes but the simplest way to do this in django is to let django handle all the sql. Not writing your own sql

Comment: upvoted just so you don't have a negative score question... Some people just love downvoting other people... It kinda compensate for what they got in their shorts... Just because you were doing something wrong doesn't mean the question has to be voted down. If you weren't doing anything wrong, you wouldn't be posting a question on here in the first place...

Comment: okey thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @Debujang https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it is not recommended to user raw SQL for such simple queries. It is quite easy to update some record with django ORM:

```
Entry.objects.filter(id=10).update(comments_on=False)
```

As for your question you can do it this way. In your template:

```
{% for keluarga in kels %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="kel" id="kel{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ keluarga.KelID }}">
    <label for="kel{{ forloop.counter }}">Choice {{ forloop.counter }}</label>
{% endfor %}
```

And in your view:

```
kels = request.POST.getlist('kel')
Kel.objects.filter(id__in=kels).update(StatApprov=3)
```

Comment: The loop seems pointless. Why not `Kel.objects.filter(id__in=kels).update(...)`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman you are right it is much better. I will update my answer, thank you.

Comment: Does in url use multiple parameter too, to get "id"? or just use like this 

    `url(r'^karyawan/update/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.update_kel_stat, name='update')`

Comment: @Debujang you may stay urls as it is now. No need to modify it since ids will pass to the view from POST form.